# Consistens width of :first-letter with CSS

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I’m trying to draw a circle around the first letter of each first paragraph in an article using `border-radius` and `padding`, but because of the different widths of the characters, it will be displayed as an ellipse rather than as a circle.

Is there any possibility to set width and height of a letter to the same amount with CSS or to set the padding so that it matches together with the width the height of any character?

My current code looks like this:

```
p:first-of-type:first-letter{
  font-size: 58px;
  line-height: 1;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 0 14px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Per @web-tiki - The ::first-letter pseudo element doesn't allow the width property. The only solution would be to use a monospace font or to use a container for the first letter. It would allow specifying a with for it an keep the circle round.

Building on web-tiki's excellent answer, you could size everything in `em` so it reacts to font-size changes as well.

```css
span {
  font-size: 58px;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: .1em
}
p:nth-of-type(even) span {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<p><span>A</span>pple</p>

<p><span>Q</span>uestionable</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who may not want to add an extra element around each first letter, another solution would be using a svg as a background-image:

```
p:first-of-type:first-letter{
background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgaGVpZ2h0PSI1OCIgd2lkdGg9IjU4Ij4KICA8Y2lyY2xlIGN4ID0iMjkiIGN5ID0iMjkiIHIgPSIyOSIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6IzQ0NDQ0NDtzdHJva2U6bm9uZTsiIC8+Cjwvc3ZnPgo=");
padding:0px 15px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center center;
}
```